# excel rename multiple sheet names from list

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, xlsx, xlrd

I have multiple sheets in excel converted from dataframe. I have collected the sheetnames in a list. I want to change the sheetname to the duplicate column values in which I have collected as shown below.
Here is my code:

```
dups = df.set_index('Group').index.get_duplicates()
```

After converting from dataframe to excel I have collected the sheetnames in a list.

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('filename', on_demand=True)
sheets=xls.sheet_names
```

I also used as shown below:

```
for i in group: #names to be renamed, collected as list 
    wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
    worksheet = wb.get_sheet_names()
    worksheet.title = i
wb1.save('file.xlsx')
```

But, I got the AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'title'.

Now, I want to rename the sheets to the dups value.
I would like to know if it is possible.
Pleased to hear some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `openpyxl` for this:

```
import openpyxl

file_loc = 'myexcel.xlsx'

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_loc)
worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
worksheet.title = 'MySheetName'
workbook.save(file_loc)
```

You can run this in a loop to rename all the sheets. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Can you please give me an example to use a loop to rename all the sheets. Sheets are not fixed it can be 15 sheets or 25 sheets. Depends on the input data.

Comment: I got the AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'title'. Any suggestions please.

Comment: @Vishali I pasted the tested solution. I am able to rename the excel sheet by the new name. Can you please share your code?

Comment: I edited my question. I posted my code, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to iterate over the workbook using `for sheet in wb`

Here is an example:

```py
import openpyxl
import os
    
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Vahan\\Desktop\\xlsx')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')

for sheet in wb: # or wb.worksheets
    sheet.title = 'RenamedSheets'
    
wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

This functionality may help you achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's better if you can explain your code instead of just pasting it in.